# In SwiftUI, how to fill Path with text color on top of a material?

Tags: swiftui

I'm drawing icons on a toolbar with a material background. The `Text` and symbol `Images` are white, but if I draw my own `Path`, it's gray.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Hi")
            Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up.fill")
            Path { p in
                p.addRect(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 20, height: 30)))
            }.fill()
            .frame(width: 20, height: 30)
        }
        .padding()
        .background(.regularMaterial)
    }
}
```

I get the same result with `.fill()`, `.fill(.foreground)`, or `.fill(.primary)`.

Why is it gray? How do I get it to match the white text color?

Comment: Weird that `.white` or `.black` work but `.primary` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I find it weird that `.white` or `.black` work, but `.primary` doesn't.

Upon discovering the [`Material`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/material) documentation, I found this interesting snippet:

> When you add a material, foreground elements exhibit vibrancy, a context-specific blend of the foreground and background colors that improves contrast. However using foregroundStyle(_:) to set a custom foreground style — excluding the hierarchical styles, like secondary — disables vibrancy.

Seems like you have to force a different color (see [previous edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69563295/1) which I used the environment color scheme), since hierarchical styles such as `.primary` won't work by design.

Luckily there is a way around this - you can use `colorMultiply` to fix this problem. If you set the rectangle to be `.white`, then the color multiply will make it the `.primary` color.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Hi")

            Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up.fill")

            Path { p in
                p.addRect(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 20, height: 30)))
            }
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .colorMultiply(.primary)
            .frame(width: 20, height: 30)
        }
        .padding()
        .background(.regularMaterial)
    }
}
```

Comment: I may have to do this, but I worry there is some other condition where Text/Image will behave differently, and then my path will be hardcoded at white/black. I wonder if this has something to do with "vibrancy". The docs for the `Material` struct say: "When you add a material, foreground elements exhibit vibrancy, a context-specific blend of the foreground and background colors that improves contrast."

Comment: @RobN Oh, that's a very good point - that may be the issue. I suppose this is a way to "force" the color you want? Reading those [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/material), it states `"... to set a custom foreground style — excluding the hierarchical styles, like secondary — disables vibrancy."`. So it seems like there is an exception for these hierarchical styles like `.primary`.

Comment: @RobN See my answer edit - found a much better workaround method!

Comment: I notice that a `Canvas` instead of a `Path` works. Maybe that is best, since then I'm not disabling the vibrancy. Not sure what other effects that might have.

Comment: @RobN Seems a bit overkill, did the color multiply method (in updated answer) work for you?

Comment: Yes, thank you, your workaround gives the right colors in light and dark mode, at least in this constrained example. Canvas is basically the same amount of code as with Path. I don't fully understand vibrancy and materials, so I don't know what other effects might be lost by turning it off. But I'll accept your answer soon unless someone else answers.

Answer (score -1):

There is no issue with code, your usage or expecting is not correct! Text and Image in that code has default `Color.primary` with zero code! So this is you, that messing with `.fill()` you can delete that one!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Hi")
            Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up.fill")
            Path { p in
                p.addRect(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 20, height: 30)))
            }
            .fill(Color.primary) // You can delete this line of code as well! No issue!
            .frame(width: 20, height: 30)
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.secondary.cornerRadius(5))

    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your code only works because you took off the `.background(.regularMaterial)`. That was part of my question.

Comment: So with that said, you have still issue?

Comment: Yes I don't have an answer yet, I want to use materials for backgrounds. They look great for other reasons.

Comment: If you really want that design then use UIKit Blur in SwiftUI it is much better for that work!